# Show unread posts in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Disclaimer: I'm a complete Rails n00b.

I need to present my forum users with a list of posts, where some might be 'unread'. By unread I mean that the post has a newer :updated_at timestamp than the user's last view timestamp of that post. I can't figure out the best approach for this - unread posts would obviously be unique to every user.

I tried using the 'Unread' gem but the documentation is above my comprehension, I can't get it to work (and I'm not even sure it does what I want it to do).

What's the leanest most Rails-y way to do this?

I'm on Rails 4.1.6

I currently have a user model and a post model:

```
class User
    has_many :posts
end

class Post
    belongs_to :user
end
```

See below for edits.

---

**EDIT 1:**

I tried following the example below of adding a Looks model, and I think I'm much closer to a solution (although not all the way there). Here's what I did:

1) `rails g model Look post:references user:references` + `rake db:migrate`. This obviously generated the model needed:

```
class Look  
    belongs_to :post  
    belongs_to :user  
end
```

2) Edited my User and Post models:

```
class User  
  has_many :posts, through: :looks  
  has_many :looks  
end

class Post  
  belongs_to :user  
  has_many :looks  
  has_many :users, through: :looks  
end
```

3) Went into `rails console`:

```
user1 = User.first

post1 = Post.first
post2 = Post.last

look = Look.create(user: user1, post: post1)
look = Look.create(user: user1, post: post2)
```

4) I now tried to spit out the results:

```
seen = user1.posts
seen.map(&:title)
```

This works fine, it gives me the result of `user1` having seen those two posts.

5) Then I tried just spitting out the IDs of the seen posts:

```
ids = Look.where(user: user1).pluck(:post_id)
```

This also works fine, I get a map of seen post ids `=> [2, 30]`

6) I then managed to get around duplicate IDs by putting a `.uniq`at the end of `User.first.posts.map(&:id).uniq`

**7) This is where I get stuck!**:

**Applying `has_many :posts, through: :looks` ruins the current relationship between a user and a post (the user_id is not included when creating a post). Here is my PostsController:**

```
def create
  @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)

  if @post.save
    redirect_to @post
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

private

def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content, :sticky, :ama_post, :post_url)
end
```

This is the last hurdle. I just need to make sure the user_id is included when creating a post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presuming you have a typical setup with many users and many posts, and you want to keep track whether any user has looked at any post, then you need to associate the users and posts by using a third model that joins a specific user to a specific post.

Start with the Rails guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Example models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :looks
  has_many :posts, through: looks
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :looks
  has_many :users, through: looks
end

class Look < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
end
```

Let's set up some sample data using the rails console:

```
alice = User.create(name: "Alice")

post1 = Post.create(name: "Post 1")
post2 = Post.create(name: "Post 2")
post3 = Post.create(name: "Post 3")
post4 = Post.create(name: "Post 4")

look = Look.create(user: alice, post: post1)
look = Look.create(user: alice, post: post2)
```

To find the posts that a user has seen:

```
seen = alice.posts
seen.map(&:name)
=> ["Post 1", "Post 2"]
```

To find the posts that a user has *not* seen:

```
ids = seen.map(&:id)
unseen = Post.where("id not in (?)", ids)
unseen.map(&:name)
=> ["Post 3", "Post 4"]
```

This is a simple way to get the records you want.

After you get this working, there are better ways to get the records by using query optimizations.

For example, you can retrieve much less data by getting just the id numbers. Here are a few ways.

```
# Basic: traverses two joins, then loads all columns
ids = Post.joins(:looks => :user).where("users.id = ?", alice.id).map(&:id)

# Faster: traverses two joins, then loads one column
ids = Post.joins(:looks => :user).where("users.id = ?", alice.id).pluck(:id)

# Fastest: no joins, and only loads one column
ids = Look.where(user: alice).pluck(:post_id)
```

Take a look at the [unread gem](https://github.com/ledermann/unread) for guidance and example code.

Comment: Would this actually make it possible to use the :updated_at attribute to figure out if the post is "new" (brand new and unseen AND/OR updated since last view)?

Comment: I had a look at the Unread gem but I'm not understanding it, it seems a few steps are missing from the tutorial, or it's simply above my current level.

Comment: Wouldn't `has_many :posts, through: looks` ruin the original relationship between a post and the post author, since I'm using `user has_many :posts` for that purpose?

Comment: To answer my own question above: yes, the `through: :looks` line breaks the user ownership of a Post. Newly created posts now fail to render the user name, user image, etc.

Comment: See my edit in the original post. I have gotten pretty far thanks to your suggestions, just need some help on the final stretch!

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need some sort of historical log. It can either log individual instances, or merely log the latest visit to the forum.

Here's a hypothetical scenario:

- Your forum has only one forum group.
- You have a User model for each user.
- You have a Topic/Thread model that contains the individual topic, with a has_many relationship to:
- The Post model which contains a specific post authored by a specific user (not relevant to answer but part of scenario)
- Your forum has a Topic controller with the standard RESTful resource routes assigned.

What you want to do is separate/highlight/designate the unread topics from the read topics, right? Breaking that down, you need to:

1. Figure out when the user last visited the forum's index page.
2. Get a list of topics.
3. When rendering each topic in the list, determine whether the topic is more "recent" than the user's last visit. Regardless of whether it was created after the last visit, or had a post after the last visit.
4. Render it differently (or whatever) as per your requirements.

Turning that into a very simple implementation, you would:

- Add a "last index visit" attribute to the User.
- Load that value when visiting the index.
- Render the topics accordingly.
- Update the last index visit attribute on the current user (best implemented as an after_action)

Now this implementation assumes that you only want to keep track of it in one place and are OK with the limitations associated with that choice (reading an individual topic won't mark it as read).

If you wanted to, you could eliminate that limitation by creating a table that belongs to both the user and the topic, and then updating that table whenever the user 'reads' the topic (depending on whether you want them to view the topic or just see it in the index).

### EDIT

To ultimately answer this question, you need to break it down into more details. "Identify unread topics" means you need to answer:

- When do I consider a topic read? Is it when I view the individual posts since it is 'new'? Is it when I see the topic in a list after it is 'new'?
- What do I consider a new/updated topic? Is it when it's first posted? what happens if someone posts a reply?

### EDIT 2

Then I'd do the following:

- Add a `touch: true` statement to the Post model's association to the Topic to ensure the updated_at attribute on the topic is modified whenever another post is made/edited.
- Create a view helper method to determine whether the current user's last reading (if any) is later than the Topic's updated_at timestamp.
- Create an `after_action` only on `Posts#show` that creates/updates the Reading for that user & topic.

Comment: I have actually experimented with timestamps and gotten it to work (kind of), but it's not the desired behaviour. I think I need to get closer to your last suggestion (and the first answer in this thread), which is to have a third model that is a relationship between a user and a post. I just need to figure out how this would be done.

Comment: Looking at the first answer, you'll want to create a New Reading whenever you visit a page.

Comment: To answer your edited questions:

1. Post is considered read as soon as you view the post page.

2. Post is considered new if it's brand new (you have never visited its page), OR if it has been updated since you last viewed its page (I assume this is through the :updated_at attribute)

Comment: Thanks. I wonder if this can be combined somehow with my edited original post. I have gotten pretty far, but struggle to move on beyond being able to log views. I assume I somehow need to apply a timestamp to the logged view. See edited OP.